# Combine result from 2 between date and personstatus column (Sql query)

Tags: mysql, sql

i have one questions.First one my table structure is in bellow:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1FgO.png)

In this table have datetime column and personstatus column,example user is selected 2 date first is 2017-07-03 second is 2017-07-05,how to display results IN ONE ROW how is MIN(id) in 2017-07-03 with personstatus='i' and how is MAX(id) in  2017-07-03 with personstatus='o',

MIN(id) in 2017-07-05 with personstatus='i' and how is MAX(id) in  2017-07-05 with personstatus='o',bellow is added table results.[table and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9kCR.png)

THANKS.

Comment: No pictures thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cc3ec/22

```
Create Table t(
  id int,
  _date datetime,
  personstatus char(5)
);

Insert Into t(id, _date, personstatus)
Values
(1,'2017-07-03 10:00:00','i'),
(2,'2017-07-03 10:10:37','i'),
(3,'2017-07-03 16:10:00','o'),
(4,'2017-07-03 17:40:27','o'),
(5,'2017-07-05 09:10:22','i'),
(6,'2017-07-05 09:30:43','i'),
(7,'2017-07-05 17:44:02','o'),
(8,'2017-07-05 17:50:19','o');

Select @input := '2017-07-03';

Select 
  t1.*, t2.*
From
  (Select * From t Where DATE(_date) = @input Order by _date ASC Limit 1) t1
Join
  (Select * From t Where DATE(_date) = @input Order by _date DESC Limit 1) t2
```

Updated 11/Aug/2017:

There are many ways to select between two dates. For example, you can:
1. make a procedure with the above queue, loop through the dates and call the procedure; or
2. create a temp table with the dates between the two dates, and then join the temp table with the t1 and t2; or
3. loop through the dates and call the queue.

I don't have a MySQL server with me right now; hope you can work out the following pseudo code:

```
declare @start date
declare @end date

set @start = '2017-02-03'
set @end = '2017-02-05'

while (@start <= @end) begin
  Select 
    t1.*, t2.*
  From
    (Select * From t Where DATE(_date) = @start Order by _date ASC Limit 1) t1
  Join
    (Select * From t Where DATE(_date) = @start Order by _date DESC Limit 1) t2

  set @start = dateadd(day, 1, @start)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this good answer @Leo.W ,but how to make 2 date range,example;

Min id in 2017-02-03, Max id in 2017-02-03,
Min id in 2017-02-04, Max id in 2017-02-04,

Min id in 2017-02-05, Max id in 2017-02-05

Im trying this query but not is correct result

Select 
  t1.*, t2.*
From
  (Select * From t Where _date >=  '2017-02-03 00:00:00'
AND _date <=  '2017-07-05 23:59:59' Order by _date ASC ) t1
Join
  (Select * From t Where date >=  '2017-02-03 00:00:00'
AND _date <=  '2017-07-05 23:59:59' Order by _date DESC ) t2